# Link for salesforce for outlook plugin version 2.4

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook, outlook

Can anyone give me the link for salesforce outlook version 2.4 not 2.5

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=outlookcrm_download_installer.htm&language=en_US